# Java ObjectInpuStream reading DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, swing, object, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

There is a class saving a DefaultTableModel of an other class.

```
file_path = new File( "c://Database//Directory//" );

file_table_stock_save = new File( file_path , "stockfile.file" );

file_path.mkdirs();

try
{

 file_path..createNewFile();

 fileoutputstream = new FileOutputStream( file_table_stock_save );

 objectoutputstream = new ObjectOutputStream( fileoutputstream );

 objectoutputstream.writeObject( stock.defaulttablemodel );

 objectoutputstream.close();

 fileoutputstream.close();

}

  catch( Exception exception )
  {.....}
```

Now here is how the DefaultTableModel is read

```
file = new File( "C://Database//Directory//" , "stockfile.file" );
        
object = new Object();
        
if( file.exists() )
{
        
 try
 {
        
  fileinputstream = new FileInputStream( file );
  objectinputstream = new ObjectInputStream( fileinputstream );
        
  object = objectinputstream.readObject();
        
  objectinputstream.close();
  fileinputstream.close();
        
 }
        
 catch( Exception exception )
 {}
        
 try
 {
        
  if( !( object == null ) )
  defaulttablemodel = ( DefaultTableModel ) object;
        
 }
        
 catch( Exception exception )
 {......}
```

The problem is the file always exists but sometimes the file is unable to be read. How to figure out the problem? Should the class implements serializable?
Can a null cell in a JTable causes an error while reading it?

Comment: Note that this: `catch( Exception exception )
 {}` is extremely bad practice

Comment: What does 'unable to be read' mean?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I would never serialize a DefaultTableModel, as otherwise you are serializing things that you don't want to serialize, including listeners and whatnot. Best to keep it simple, and serialize the data, and only the data. I would serialize its data vector that holds the data of interest. Use that to rebuild a new table model with the retrieved data.

Fortunately DefaultTableModel has a method, `.getDataVector()` that retrieves from the model a `Vector<Vector>` that holds all the data within the model. I would use this to save and retrieve the data, if you *must* use serialization.

In the code below, I have a simple class that extends DefaultTableModel, and that allows re-creation of the model with a data vector, using a constant Vector to hold the table headings:

```
class MyModel extends DefaultTableModel {
    public static final String[] HEADERS = { "One", "Two", "Three" };
    public static final Vector<String> V_HEADERS = new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(HEADERS));

    public MyModel(Vector<Vector<Object>> data) {
        super(data, V_HEADERS);
    }

    public MyModel() {
        super(HEADERS, 0);
    }

}
```

I can then serialize and unserialize the data held by the model via this code to serialize:

```
// assuming that the model is held in a variable called "myModel"
Vector tableData = myModel.getDataVector();
        // file name is held by DATA_FILE String constant
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(DATA_FILE); 
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);) {
    oos.writeObject(tableData);  // writes my data 

} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace(); // always catch and handle exceptions
}
```

and I can read the data back into a model and then into the JTable via:

```
// again DATA_FILE is our file's name
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(DATA_FILE); 
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {
    // read the data vector in with the ObjectInputStream
    Vector<Vector<Object>> tableData = (Vector<Vector<Object>>) ois.readObject();
    
    // create a new table model with the data
    myModel = new MyModel(tableData);
    
    // set the JTable with the new model
    table.setModel(myModel);
} catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

A working example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Gui01 extends JPanel {
    public static final String DATA_FILE = "tableData.dat";
    private MyModel myModel = new MyModel();
    private JTable table = new JTable(myModel);

    public Gui01() {
        int maxRow = 5;
        for (int row = 0; row < maxRow; row++) {
            Vector<Object> rowData = new Vector<>();
            for (int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++) {
                Integer cell = row * table.getColumnCount() + col;
                rowData.add(cell);
            }
            myModel.addRow(rowData);
        }

        saveTable();

        JButton saveTableBtn = new JButton("Save Table");
        saveTableBtn.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        saveTableBtn.addActionListener(e -> saveTable());

        JButton clearTableBtn = new JButton("Clear Table");
        clearTableBtn.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        clearTableBtn.addActionListener(e -> clearTable());

        JButton retrieveTableBtn = new JButton("Retrieve Table");
        retrieveTableBtn.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        retrieveTableBtn.addActionListener(e -> retrieveTable());

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(saveTableBtn);
        buttonPanel.add(clearTableBtn);
        buttonPanel.add(retrieveTableBtn);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(table));
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private void saveTable() {
        Vector tableData = myModel.getDataVector();
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(DATA_FILE);
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);) {
            oos.writeObject(tableData);

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void clearTable() {
        myModel.setRowCount(0);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void retrieveTable() {
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(DATA_FILE); 
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {
            Vector<Vector<Object>> tableData = (Vector<Vector<Object>>) ois.readObject();
            myModel = new MyModel(tableData);
            table.setModel(myModel);
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Gui01 mainPanel = new Gui01();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Gui01");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

```
class MyModel extends DefaultTableModel {
    public static final String[] HEADERS = { "One", "Two", "Three" };
    public static final Vector<String> V_HEADERS = new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(HEADERS));

    public MyModel(Vector<Vector<Object>> data) {
        super(data, V_HEADERS);
    }

    public MyModel() {
        super(HEADERS, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try to compile your  "MyModel" class I get the error messge: *no suitable constructor found for DefaultTableModel(Vector<Object>,Vector<String>)
        super(data, V_HEADERS);*. The parameter for the DefaultTableModel should be `Vector<Vector<Object>>` not a `Vector<Object>` I believe.

Comment: @camickr: thank you for checking this. For some reason, it ran on my PC (perhaps with an earlier version of Java). I have updated the code, so hopefully it works for every version of Java. Again, I sincerely thank you for this.

Comment: (1+) works for me now.